# why we need to call $scope.$apply inside dom event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the value not getting updated when i click on the `update-time` button.

```
<html ng-app="domC">
    <head>
        <title>Angularjs DOM </title>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            {{data.time}}

            <br/>
            <button ng-click="updateTime()">update time - ng-click</button>
            <button id="updateTimeButton"  >update time</button>
        </div>
        <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var module = angular.module("domC", []);
            var myController1 = module.controller("myController", function($scope) {

                $scope.data = { time : new Date() };

                $scope.updateTime = function() {
                    $scope.data.time = new Date();
                }

                document.getElementById("updateTimeButton")
                        .addEventListener('click', function() {
                    console.log("update time clicked");
                    $scope.data.time = new Date();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that this piece of code below won't update the `$scope.data.time` to `new Date()`;

```
document.getElementById("updateTimeButton")
     .addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log("update time clicked");
      $scope.data.time = new Date();
});
```

I have two `questions` on this.

1. Why do we need to use `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.data.time});` inside my dom event listener to update the value, **why does the normal way not work.**
2. Why not call `$scope.$digest()` instead of $scope.$apply() which internally again calls the $scope.$digest to iterate over all watchers.

Answer (score 1):

1) Because you need to notify to Angular that your scope has changed. You dont need to do this if you use `ng-click`, this will internally do it for you.

2) You have no reason to call the digest, as you said, apply will call it after it applies your changes to the scope. Forcing the digest may fail at that point and may do unexpected actions.

Comment: Why does it not work in normal dom listners?. I am still updating the $scope.date.time inside my event listener?.

Comment: Because thats how Angular works, it lets you change the scope, but it needs to be notified when the scope modifications finish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't access the DOM from the controller. Controller should not know or make any assumptions about the View.

Instead, in the View use `ng-click` directive to change the scope. Coincidentally, you would not need to do `$scope.$apply()`:

```
<button id="updateTimeButton" ng-click="updateTime">Update Time</button>
```

Then, in the controller:

```
$scope.updateTime = function(){
   $scope.data.time = new Date();
}
```

Otherwise, @lante answered your question about why `$scope.$apply` is needed. Sometimes, it is really needed when you work with non-Angular libraries that do async or event-based manipulations. **BUT** not in your case - in your case, you needed it because you were not following best practices, and you will run into many other issues and headaches if you continue to do so.